# Chain Line - Front Coming Off

Tags: chainline

A bike I am taking back from a single speed (SS) to  multi speed
(like ss - bought another ss)

Used 9 speed SRAM 7 that I got cheap

I am just going to stay single in the front
That is a Race Face 34 (ss designed ring)

My problem is chain line
In first it will jump off the front chain ring to the inside
It does fine in second gear

As you can see there is one spacer on font crank right
There are two on the left
It was two on the right and I flopped that - got me 2nd gear
All three on the left did not seem like a good ideal - left would barely get some threads

Tried putting a spacer on the inside of the cassette but there is absolutely no room
I can barely get the cassette on with no spacer

Short of a chain keeper are there any ideas?

I am not opposed to a chain keeper but I want to also fix the chain line.

Picture does show the problem very well
In 3rd (from smallest) the chain line is straight where on a 9 speed that should be 5th
[image: Chain line - picture does show the problem very well]

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog How would putting the chainring outside help?  That is the wrong direction.

Comment: Do you have a picture of what your derailleur looks like with the chain in that same position?

Comment: @ChrisinAK Why would you need a derailleur picture?   The cassette switches fine.  Chain is coming off the chain ring from the top side.  Chain is not coming off the cassette.

Comment: I have run setups similar to this before and had less issues with the setup when there was lots of tension on the chain.  To the point that the derailleur is jacked almost straight out in the largest (diameter) cog.

Comment: @ChrisinAK But the biggest gear is the maximum tension and the only one with the problem.  The chain has good tension.  I definitely have a chain line issue.  3 is lined up when ideally it would be 5.

Comment: Does this single speed cog have more thickness than a multispeed one would since it doesn't need to give any wiggle room for a moving chain?  And wouldn't a 9 speed chain be more narrow taking out some of that wiggle room?

Comment: @BPugh Yes a 9 speed chain is more narrow.  You really think I would be getting 2-9 without a 9 speed chain?  A SS chain would not even fit in 2 as pictured.